# Loop through XML Nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing, document, whmcs

I am pulling some data from a website in XML format and it works fine when there are not consecutive nodes, but I am having trouble figuring out how to loop through them when there is. The data that I get looks something like...

```
 <whmcsapi> 
  <action>gettickets</action> 
  <numreturned>1</numreturned> 
  <tickets> 
   <ticket>  
    <tid>557168</tid> 
    <name><![CDATA[Array]]></name> 
    <subject><![CDATA[Test Ticket]]></subject> 
    <message><![CDATA[This is a test ticket>
   <ticket>
   <ticket>
    <tid>557168</tid> 
    <name><![CDATA[Array]]></name> 
    <subject><![CDATA[Test Ticket]]></subject> 
    <message><![CDATA[This is a test ticket>
   <ticket>
```

How can I loop through and read the data from each  node? My code right now is the following...

```
    public List<Ticket> Get_Tickets()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> args = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        args.Add("status", "All Active Tickets");

        string data = Get_Data("gettickets", args);
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(data);

        //var support_tickets = doc.Descendants("ticket").Select(ticket => new
        List<Ticket> support_tickets = (from x in doc.Descendants("ticket") select new Ticket
        {
            ID = x.Element("id").Value,
            TicketID = x.Element("tid").Value,
            DeptID = x.Element("deptid").Value,
            UserID = x.Element("userid").Value,
            Name = x.Element("name").Value,
            Email = x.Element("email").Value,
            Subject = x.Element("subject").Value,
            Message = x.Element("message").Value,
        }).ToList();

        return support_tickets;
    }
```

The Ticket class...

```
public class Ticket
{
    public string ID;
    public string TicketID;
    public string DeptID;
    public string UserID;
    public string Name;
    public string Email;
    public string CC;
    public string Subject;
    public string Message;
    public string Status;
    public string Priority;
    public DateTime Date;
    public DateTime LastResponse;
    public IPAddress IP;
}
```

Comment: Try `doc.Descendants("ticket")` (note the singular) - that should give you all the ticket sets.  Also, there is no element named `id` that I see in the XML you're showing, so that will throw an error.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try! The XML I pasted was not complete as the original is quite long. I just chopped it down a bit to keep it readable.

Comment: I just realized I cannot return a var from my function. What would be the best way to return the data from this?

Comment: It's not in your posted code, but are you trying to load Ticket.IP in the new Ticket block as well?  According to the docs (http://docs.whmcs.com/API:Get_Tickets), it looks like IP Address is contained in the CData in the `message` tag.  That could be another source of the object reference error you referenced below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Ticket> supportTickets = 
    (from x in doc.Descendants("ticket")
     select new Ticket
     {
         ID = x.Element("id").Value,
         TicketID = x.Element("tid").Value,
         DeptID = x.Element("deptid").Value,
         UserID = x.Element("userid").Value,
         Name = x.Element("name").Value,
         Email = x.Element("email").Value,
         Subject = x.Element("subject").Value,
         Message = x.Element("message").Value,
     }).ToList();
```

You can try this code. If you try to get back the value of a Element which doesn't exist, it will throw an exception.

Comment: I created a container class called "Ticket" and gave it all of these as members but ticket.Element is not recognized as it doesn't exist

Comment: I would avoid using `XElement` in the LINQ query, as that's a .NET class.  `(from x in doc.Descendants("ticket")...` would be better, and then you could do `x.Element("id").Value`, etc.

Comment: @BrettPowell - Can you update your question with your new code?  The answer above (at a glance) should work.  I wrote a quick test app using your code (except I changed Descendants("tickets") to "ticket") and it worked.

Comment: I just updated my question with the latest code. It all looks to be correct but I am no good with the XML syntax and cannot find a good tutorial on it for the life of me. I am getting a "Object Reference not set to an Instance of an Object" error for the "new Ticket {...}" code.

Comment: @BrettPowell are you testing this against the complete XML, or the just the snippet you posted above?  The most likely cause of the error is that one of the elements you're referencing inside new Ticket is not in the XML being parsed.

Comment: That was indeed the issue. Once I viewed it via XML I could see that the "message" was missing for one of them. Is there any type of safeguard I can use to prevent a crash from this? Thanks so much for the help both of you!

Comment: you can create an method which check if the item is not in the xml or if is empty : x.Element(key) == null || x.Element(key).IsEmpty